# How to use cordova-plugin-googleplus and cordova-plugin-firebasex together

Tags: firebase, cordova, cordova-plugins, google-signin

I have a cordova app that uses [cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) for google signin and [cordova-plugin-firebasex](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex) for push notifications. Either of these plugins on their own work fine but when I try to use them together in my cordova project I get issues. I believe this has to do with the plugins wanting to install conflicting versions of Google Play Service but I can't figure out how to resolve the issue.

If I already have `cordova-plugin-firebasex` installed:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex \
--variable ANDROID_PLAY_SERVICES_AUTH_VERSION=15.0.1
```

which works fine and the app compiles and runs. But when and I try to installed `cordova-plugin-googleplus` I get this

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus  \
--variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=com.myapp.whatever \
--variable WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID=whatever.myapp.com \
--variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=15.0.1

Installing "cordova-plugin-googleplus" for ios

cordova-plugin-googleplus depends on GoogleSignIn, which may conflict with another plugin. GoogleSignIn@6.2.1 is already installed and was not overwritten.
```

The documentation for `cordova-plugin-googleplus` states this:

> To set up Google Play Services version, you can use PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION parameter (with 11.8.0 value by default). It is useful in order to avoid conflicts with another plugins which use any other different version of Google Play Service, because they MUST be the same version.

which I am attempting to use along with the `ANDROID_PLAY_SERVICES_AUTH_VERSION` setting from the [cordova-plugin-firebasex docs](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex#android-specific) but it doesn't seem to make any difference.